# How can I modify the calendar height dynamically?

Tags: swift, fscalendar

I'm trying to modify the calendar's height programmatically by modifying its height constraint programmatically but the calendar won't resize its content.
The view's frame is updated correctly because I have other views constrained to the bottom and they move, but the content won't adapt.

I set height constraint to 0 in viewDidLoad() method. Then changed height to 220 on button tap. Height of view is changing and title is showing, but date cells are not showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to remove height constraint in viewDidLoad() method